# Physical address vs virtual address

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, mac-address

It's possible to generate a physical address by a virtual machine such that when real and virtual machine are connected to the network, nobody in the network can determine which one is a virtual address?

Comment: Do you mean memory virt/phys address or network MAC/IP addresses?

Comment: I meant network physical address.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44004888/781723, https://superuser.com/q/1209911.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the MAC address of the device and preventing people from enumerating the MAC to get the vendor, you can change the MAC in a few ways:

- In most virtualization software, you can specify the MAC of each adapter. Check the properties of your network controller in your VM solution to see if you can do it this way as it will be easier (and cleaner) to do the configuration here.
- In most major OS'es you can just change the MAC to whatever you want so if your VM software doesn't allow you to specify the MAC, the guest OS should have no issues with it.

Edit: As pointed out, if it is about a MAC address, this should probably be posted/moved to the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) stack (for business) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) stack (for home/personal) questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I amended my answer to include a link to the proper stack with a suggestion to move or re-post there.